# Cannot install packages with apt in docker image

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services, dockerfile, networking, amazon-rds

I'm trying to create my own `postgres` image that is supposed to connect to a `postgreSQL` database hosted on `AWS RDS`, however, I'm having trouble connecting to that database as well as trouble installing some required packages. The base image is `postgres:11.16`, with debian as the underlying os as per the `cat /etc/os-release` which gives the output:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
VERSION_CODENAME=stretch
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

My `dockerfile` is defined as:

```
FROM postgres:11.16

ENV DB_HOST=host_name.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
ENV PORT=5432
ENV DB_NAME=db_name
ENV DB_USER=user
ENV DB_PASSWORD=pass

EXPOSE 5432 80

# RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get update && RUN apt-get install -y iputils-ping

RUN mkdir -p app

COPY *.sql ./app/

COPY entrypoint.sh ./app/

RUN chmod +x /app/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

with the `entrypoint.sh` script being:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$DB_HOST $PORT $DB_NAME $DB_USER $DB_PASSWORD"

# Wait for the PostgreSQL server to be fully running
until psql "host=$DB_HOST port=$PORT dbname=$DB_NAME user=$DB_USER password=$DB_PASSWORD" -c "SELECT 1" >/dev/null 2>&1; do
    echo "Waiting for PostgreSQL server to start..."
    sleep 1
done

# Execute the SQL script
psql "host=$DB_HOST port=$PORT dbname=$DB_NAME user=$DB_USER password=$DB_PASSWORD" -f /app/evaluation.sql
```

At first I just wanted to connect to the database, but it just kept printing the `echo` message in the `entrypoint.sh` script. So I wanted to check if the remote server is reachable with `ping`, however, it was not installed by default on `debian` and I tried to install it, but then I ran into more problems. I then tried to install the `ping` binaries from the definition of the `dockerfile` but still the same error persisted:

```
 => ERROR [2/6] RUN apt-get update && RUN apt-get install -y iputils-ping                                                                                                                                                               4.0s
------
 > [2/6] RUN apt-get update && RUN apt-get install -y iputils-ping:
pgdg/11/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 217.196.149.55 80]
#5 3.974 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && RUN apt-get install -y iputils-ping]: exit code: 100
```

Even though the ports 80 and 5432 are exposed and mapped, as per `docker container ps`:

```
0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp
```

I still think this might be a networking issue. Any help towards resolving this issue is welcome.

Comment: For the apt returning 404 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76094428/debian-stretch-repositories-404-not-found. For the rest you don't specify where you run the docker image. If you are on local machine the AWS RDS may not be reachable, if you are on EC2 you may have not set Security Groups correctly. I am not sure why you need image with PostgreSQL if you are using AWS RDS... all you need is `psql` - search how to install "psql". Good luck.